# Can anyone help me with getting cucumber-jvm reporting in TeamCity?

Tags: webdriver, teamcity-7.0, cucumber-jvm

I have managed to make some great strides recently on my way to understanding how CI systems integrate with source control, etc.

One of the things I am struggling to find out there is how I am able to get better reporting when it comes to cucumber-jvm and TeamCity. I have a sea of horrid looking text that I see as TeamCity progresses through my BDD (Webdriver) tests.

Does anyone know of/have any experience with reporting, explicitly for cucumber-jvm with TeamCity?

I have tried the usual suspects; google, blogs, GitHub pages, etc, but to no avail.

The best one I have seen is this...but its on Jenkins.

[cucumber-jvm reporting on Jenkins](https://github.com/masterthought/jenkins-cucumber-jvm-reports-plugin-java)

I am also currently looking at things like the surefire reports, etc too. But it would be great to have something within TeamCity itself.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting to generate reports.. Refer Teamcity custom reports to include the cucumber reports in your build config https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results ..